# Creating and using a jar with non-text-resources

Tags: java, selenium, jar, selenium-chromedriver, relative-path

I'm trying to create a jar that enables people to launch web browser drivers through this library. 
So the idea is to have one project "ToBecomeJar" have chromedriver (does not have a file extension) as an item in a "drivers" folder and using it in its code as:

```
private WebDriver getDriver(){
    System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY, "drivers/chromedriver");
    driver =new ChromeDriver();

    return driver;
}
```

The issue here is that when I turn this project into a library, of course the "PathToDriver" will be taken as an absolute path when used, leading to my new project needing path structure exactly the same as the library with the driver there.

Is there any way to make this relative?

I've tried working with a resource folder and calling the resource with .getResource but I really can't manage to make it work. When looking into this people mention that it should become .getResourceStream as it becomes something other then a file, but that doesn't work for me as it's not a text file I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 'user.dir' which is an environment var of the JVM. 
It can be used to construct the path string of your driver executable:

```
private WebDriver getDriver(){
    System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER_PROPERTY, System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/drivers/chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, it formats the path just the same way as my bit of code did:
C:\Projects\Workbench\ProjectB\drivers\chromedriver
The issue is that, ProjectB uses ProjectA as a library, and ProjectA contains that bit of code as well as the driver folder. So ofc it can't find it at the given path. I assume the path should be something like "C:\Projects\Workbench\ProjectB\Libs\ProjectA\drivers\chromedriver" if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the needed resources from jar to a temporary folder during the startup of your app and then point to that folder for the proper drivers.

Comment: So ProjectB triggers ProjectA (which is added as a library) containing the code to extract its own resource to a new place through resourcestream, then handles it, and then removes the newly created file when done? That's the bit where I'm lost, because that means that a getResource().toString(); should also do the trick, since the selenium method only requires a path to the driver, and not the driver itself, but that bit of code doesn't work.

Comment: But resurces are typically placed inside your jar file, selenium doesn't know how to read a driver from inside of the jar, you need to extract it somwhere selenium can pick it.

Comment: But how does it work exactly then? Do I have to do a getResource() into a File, or a getResourceStream()?

Comment: You need to unzip the driver from your jar to a particular tmp location, then point the driver to it.